# Geographic Component in PgAdmin 4

Tags: qgis, postgis, pgadmin-4

I have a college project involving GIS, but I am new to this field. I have created a database using PgAdmin 4 and have added alphanumeric data to it. Now I want to add a geographic component to a specific row in the same table. I have tried adding shapefiles, but the system keeps creating new tables with the same information. How would experts proceed in this case?

Comment: Please describe what you've done, for example how did you load the shapefile, etc. Give more context, screenshots, etc. For spatial component, look at `CREATE EXTENSION POSTGIS;` command.

Comment: How are you getting data into PostGIS?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have some way to link the shapefile data to the table you have created. Import the shapefiles to the database. Update the geometry/geography column of your table using the imported shapefiles using the linking attribute (id in the example below):

```
update your_table a set geom = b.geom from imported_shapefile_table b where a.id = b.id;
```